# Invalid implicit conversion from rational_const 5 / 2 to uint256 requested

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, dapps, ropsten

I have the following code snippet inside my contract:

```
plans[1100] = Plan(7, 3);
plans[1101] = Plan(7, 2.5);
plans[1102] = Plan(15, 4);
plans[1103] = Plan(30, 6);
plans[1104] = Plan(30, 5);
```

When I try to compile my contract, I encounter the following error:

```
CompileError: /home/nimashiri/react-dapp/contracts/TrustTrade.sol:172:31: TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from rational_const 5 / 2 to uint256 requested.
plans[1101] = Plan(7, 2.5);
```

I was wondering if you help me with this case.

Thanks,
Nima.

Comment: What is `Plan`? Solidity doesn't have floating point support. It does work for intermediate results when the final is an integer. For example `uint256 a = 2.5 * 1000` works but it fails for `uint256 a = 5 / 3 * 1000` fails.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks. Sorry, i forgot to mention `Plan`. It is a struct: `  struct Plan {uint256 period; uint256 interest;}`

Comment: The error is that you are trying to assign 2.5 to an uint256. Solidity is trying to be helpful and don't let you assign it.